# How can I parse two strings in a table row by using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
html = '''
<div class="container">
 <h2>Countries & Capitals</h2>
  <table class="two-column td-red">
  <thead><tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital city</th></tr></thead><tbody>
   <tr class="grey"><td>Afghanistan</td><td>Kabul</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Albania</td><td>Tirana</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Given this HTML, I would like to specifically parse the country name and the capital city name and put them into a dictionary so that I can get

`dict["Afghanistan] = 'Kabul'`

I've started by doing

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), 'lxml')
countries = {}
# YOUR CODE HERE
table = soup.find_all('table')
for each in table:
    if each.find('tr'):
        continue
    else:
        print(each.prettify())
return countries
```

But it's confusing since it's the first time using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the "tr" elements if they have two "td" child elements you have your data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="container">
 <h2>Countries & Capitals</h2>
  <table class="two-column td-red">
  <thead><tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital city</th></tr></thead><tbody>
   <tr class="grey"><td>Afghanistan</td><td>Kabul</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Albania</td><td>Tirana</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
countries = {}

trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all("td")
    if len (tds) ==2:
        countries[tds[0].text] = tds[1].text
print (countries)
```

Outputs:

```
{'Afghanistan': 'Kabul', 'Albania': 'Tirana'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for the given html example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # assuming you did pip install bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  # the html you mentioned
table_data = soup.find('table')
data = {}  # {'country': 'capital'} dict
for row in table_data.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = row.find_all('td')
    if row_data:
        data[row_data[0].text] = row_data[1].text
```

I've skipped the `try, except` block for any erroneous case. I suggest to go through [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) of BeautifulSoup, it covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

element ='''
<div class="container">
    <h2>Countries & Capitals</h2>
    <table class="two-column td-red">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Country</th><th>Capital city</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="grey"><td>Afghanistan</td><td>Kabul</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Albania</td><td>Tirana</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(element, 'lxml')

countries = {}
for data in soup.select("tr"):
    elem = [item.text for item in data.select("th,td")]
    countries[elem[0]] = elem[1]

print(countries)
```

Output:

```
{'Afghanistan': 'Kabul', 'Country': 'Capital city', 'Albania': 'Tirana'}
```